# Node.JS - nodemon + webpack not detecting file change over NFS

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, webpack, nfs

I need some help with nodemone and webpack. My team and I are working on a project, we are still in the early stage, but I've been fighting this issue for three days. 
We are working on a remote physical host that runs multiple VMs. Each VM is serving different purpose. I have setup an NFS share between the VM and the host. We all work from home so we upload the files via FTP to the host (actually we use Visual Studio Code with ftp-sync plugin, so when I hit the save button, the file automatically uploads to the remote folder). However, nodemon and webpack are not detecting the change in the file.

I have mounted the nfs share with the following options:

```
mount -o noac,sync <host IP address>:/path/to/folder
```

I have checked the ctime and mtime and they are in perfect sync. However, for some reason the change in the file is never detected by webpack and nodemon. If I hit touch  within the guest, it works. 
Can anyone suggest any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to find a solution literally few minutes after I posted my answer. So basically the issue was fixed by adding "--watch-poll" argument to my package.json scripts.

```
"scripts": {
"dev:build": "webpack -w --watch-poll",
"dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon dist/index.bundle.js" }
```

Right now, when I save the file within Visual Studio Code, it is automatically uploaded to the host, synced with the VM development environment and automatically re-compiled and the server restarted with nodemon.